# How to make a Xamarin.ios graph animate with dynamic loading?

Tags: io, xamarin.ios, core-graphics, core-animation

What approach should I take to implement a dynamic graph using Xamarin.ios graphics without a plugin or framework?

An example of what I mean is illustrated in the image below. The top graph in the image is swiped right and dynamically more nodes are added from the left side as illustrated in the below graph in the image.

Please note that some nodes are of not the same distance to each other. And there can come a shaded portion in the graph as well.

[image]